# Hiding objects in two column bootstrap accordion breaks formatting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a multiple section accordion set up with two column.  The page is setup something like this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="Accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Accordion" data-target="#ApplicantInfo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle">
                Applicant Information:
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="ApplicantInfo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="divApplicant" class="col-xs-6">Applicant:</div>
                <div id="divApplicantPhone" class="col-xs-6">Applicant Telephone:</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row spFieldRow">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <span dir="none">
                     <input id="applinantName" ...>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <span dir="none">
                     <input id="applinantPhone" ...>
                  </span>
                </div>
            </div>              
            <div class="row">
                <div id="divApplicantEmail" class="col-xs-6">Applicant Email:</div>
                <div id="divApplicantType" class="col-xs-6">Applicant Type:</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row spFieldRow">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <span dir="none">
                     <input id="applinantEmail" ...>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <span dir="none">
                     <input id="applinantType" ...>
                  </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the most part it works very well.  However, some of my fields are dynamic depending on the selection of one of the other fields.  The problem I am running into is that if I remove say either of the input rows or even just the text box it shrinks the width of the panel.

I have attached a couple of pics to illustrate.
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I have tried affecting entire rows, I even added a div container around the label and input containers and hiding that.  Doesn't matter, the second row shifts up and shrinks.
Please be kind, I am very new to bootstrap (my first time) and haven't done much front end development in recent years. I appreciate any assistance.

Edit: 
I created a JSFiddle as close to this as possible and can't recreate the issue ([you can find it here if you want](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/147382/)).

I completely forgot to mention prior, but this page is sitting on a SharePoint site so there is all other kinds of css being loaded.  My guess is one of them is getting in the way.  If anyone has seen this before i would appreciate any input.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can update your question with your css code

Comment: Could you also reduce the code to a [mcve] (including CSS/JS)? it would really speed up the rate at which we can find a solution/answer for you... thx

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I did up a MCVE and added it to my initial post.  I also added some key information I can't believe I forgot.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot see the issue you describe in the JSFiddle you created.  The [mcve] needs to be both, complete and verifiable.  (there is no JS in the fiddle) - also, it's best if you include the code in your question; if the link breaks for any reason, the question would be incomplete and not very helpful to others in the community

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but instead of dynamically adding the panels themselves, you can show/hide them at will.

(you can still dynamically add content to each panel as you see fit, just not the panels - they serve as containers for your dynamic content)

**See demo below** (*select an applicant type in the dropdown box*):

```js
$(function() {
  
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    
    if ($(this).val() === 'Internal') {      
      $("#externalPanel").collapse('hide');
      $("#internalPanel").removeClass('hide');
      $("#internalPanel").collapse('show');
      
    } else if ($(this).val() === 'External') {      
      $("#internalPanel").collapse('hide');
      $("#externalPanel").removeClass('hide');
      $("#externalPanel").collapse('show');
    } else {
      $(".secondary-panel").collapse('hide');      
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="ADMSAccordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ADMSAccordion" data-target="#ApplicantInfo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                    Applicant Information:
                </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="ApplicantInfo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="divApplicant" class="col-xs-6">Applicant:</div>
          <div id="divApplicantPhone" class="col-xs-6">Applicant Telephone:</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input title="Applicant" type="text" maxlength="255" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input title="ApplicantPhone" type="text" maxlength="255" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="divApplicantEmail" class="col-xs-6">Applicant Email:</div>
          <div id="divApplicantType" class="col-xs-6">Applicant Type:</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input title="ApplicantEmail" type="text" maxlength="255" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select title="ApplicantType">
              <option selected="Selected" value=""></option>
              <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
              <option value="External">External</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- External panel -->
<div id="externalPanel" class="panel panel-default hide secondary-panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">External Panel</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    External Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<!-- INternal panel -->
<div id="internalPanel" class="panel panel-default hide secondary-panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Internal Panel</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Internal Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```